# How to add a prefix to all my routes

Tags: symfony1, routes, symfony-1.4

I'm currently working on a website built with symfony 1.4 and I need to implement a route prefix for all the routes. This prefix is used to specify two differents "views" for the website, for exemple :

```
www.domain.com/b2b : B2B oriented view
www.domain.com/b2c : B2C oriented view
```

Both of these URLs render the same modules/actions but with little specific differences (textes, images, ...). So, www.domain.com/b2b/module1/action1 and www.domain.com/b2c/module1/action1 must proceed the same action/view but the prefix should be catchable in the action or template.

Is there a way to implement this without having to hard-code the prefix in every urlFor/routeFor call ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a great ressource page for your needs:
http://particul.es/blog/index.php?post/How-to-change-backend.php-to-admin-prefix-routes-automatically-symfony
With many solutions to achieve your goals. But, personnaly, I think that the smartest way for you is to handle this in .htaccess.

Comment: Thanks, I think it will be helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

You could create your own routing classes, which appends the "view" (b2b/b2c) to the route, and parses it when needed.

Create an custom class which inherits from `sfRoute`. In your `routing.yml` add `class: myRouteClassName` to the routes.

Comment: I'm already using a custom routing class for all my routes (gbI18nRoutePlugin for i18n routes). Can a route use two classes? (and sorry for my english...)

Comment: You could extend from `gbI18nRoutePlugin`.

Comment: I have really no idea how to implement this. I've just red the "custom routing" section for the documentation and this didin't help me. Do you have a link to a concrete exemple or some pieces of code to begin from ? Thanks for your help!