# Deploy symfony2 into a folder

Tags: symfony, web-deployment

As a symfony1.4 developer, I'm trying to learn Symfony2.

Now, instead of trying on my local machine, where all works fine, today I want to make my test site available on my server. But I don't want to deploy it on a real site or on a real subdomain.

And that's my question: how can I deploy this test on a subfolder without modify virtualhost?!

Lets say I have an available site, `www.example.com`, but I'd like to have my symfony test available (and working correctly) here `www.exaple.com/mysymfonytest`

Did somone already do that?

Thanks...

Comment: Have you tried putting the application in a subfolder? It should work.

Comment: No, it don't works! Example.com/mysubfolder/web/app.php redirects to example.com

Comment: It works on my computer, can you show us your webserver (apache?) website configuration?

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion that is not really a symfony related question.

Depending on your webserver you could configure an alias where which url should point.

In Apache you specify your document root, where you put your sf2 installation, and then define an alias which would be /mysymfonytest pointing to that document root.

Alternatively you could specify your document root, leave the url be and define a prefix for all routes in symfony, which you would do in your routing configuration.

I strongly recommend configuring your webserver though.

For example in apache:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/mysymfonytest
    Alias /mysymfonytest /var/www/mysymfonytest
    <Directory /var/www/mysymfonytest/web>
            AllowOverride None
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all

            #Allow from <SUPPORT>
            RewriteEngine On
            RewriteBase /mysymfonytest
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
            RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /app.php [QSA,L]
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Alternatively, if you cannot add the VHost:
[How to add a prefix to all my routes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6841400/how-to-add-a-prefix-to-all-my-routes)

Comment: ok, the virtualhost is not something I can edit, so...if I can only modify symfony files?

Answer (score 0):

make a sub-directory under `/` (root directory) and call it `mysymfonytest` then put your symfony2 project in `mysymfonytest`.

add a .htaccess file to  `mysymfonytest` folder  and put in it :

> ```
> <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
>
> RewriteEngine On
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?example.com$
> RewriteRule ^(/)?$ web [L]
>
> </IfModule>
> ```

or you can just make a file named `index.html` and make it point to `app.php`

Comment: I've already tried this solution but there should be something to adjust to make it works correctly...

Answer (score 0):

If your only running on a shared hosting. You could use override configurations using .htaccess. Ask your provide if they allow overrides and then provide them the script or tell them what you want. Hope that's covered on your hosting support.